# Perform a Git operation from different working directory

Tags: git

Is there a way to perform a git operation, say `git checkout develop`, if your current working directory (i.e. `pwd`) is not in or under the root folder (where .git\ is located)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `git -C {path}` command to tell git to move to another directory before running the given command.

For example

```
git -C ~/code/myproject checkout develop
```